# Div having an overlay does not scroll in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a scroll-able div absolute positioned on one of my pages and there is a transparent overlay placed on top of it. Have created an example below,

http://jsfiddle.net/mae8y2w4/1/

```
overflow-y: scroll; added
```

But the content does not scroll in Chrome, works fine in Mozilla. Can anyone please tell me what the issue could be.

Thanks in advance,

Neha

Comment: Works in Chrome from the jsfiddle

Comment: both the overlay and box are positioned absolute..
overlay has certain left value and top value ..
if the cursor is on overlay then it will not scroll.
let me know the purpose of overlay

Comment: I need both the divs with position absolute as I have some functionality on click of the overlay.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the last `<div>`: http://jsfiddle.net/mp0g5ab6/

Comment: Cannot remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Remove position from last div:

```
<div style=" width:150px; height:55px;"></div>
```

Comment: Need the overlay to have absolute position.